# Converting cs to vb

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, zooming

Can anyone tell me what is "j" and "i" in this .cs code?

```
private void zoom_out(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(j>0)
        {
            image1.Height -= 50;
            image1.Width -= 50;
            j--;
            i = j;
        }
    }
private void zoom_in(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       if(i<2)
        {
            image1.Height += 50;
            image1.Width += 50;
            i++;
            j = i;
        }
    }
```

And change "j" and "i" for .vb code. It is code for zooming out and in.

Comment: They are the current zoom position variables. They must be declared in the class like Private i, j as integer

Comment: So what can I do instead of "i" and "j"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe they are a programming concept most commonly termed 'variables'. They are used to store application state and perform computations.

Comment: lol - well what do you know, the obvious answer was the correct one ;)

Comment: More info from Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242127(v=vs.60).aspx